# Docker : Drupal container linked to mysql container can't connect to mysql during Drupal installation

Tags: mysql, drupal, docker

I'm fairly new to docker, and I've just been going through the CMS's to see how easy they are to configure. So far, Wordpress and Joomla check out.

When I run the drupal container linked to mysql, I get to the drupal installation screen and where it says to connect the DB, and I use my root credentials and db host being 'localhost', and receive errors trying to connect. I've attached an image to show you the output.[drupal-config-db-output-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnD3Q.jpg)

The error I get :

```
Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory.
```

Any help on this would be great. I tried to see if I could access the physical the volume with the config files, but I couldn't find them using Kitematic.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) file will startup Drupal connected to another container running Mysql

```
db:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=letmein
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal
    - MYSQL_USER=drupal
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=drupal
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql
web:
  image: drupal
  links:
    - db:mysql
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - /var/www/html/sites
    - /var/www/private
```

Note that the drupal container uses [docker links](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/). This will create a /etc/hosts entry called "mysql". Use this instead of "localhost" when running the drupal install screens.

---

### Note

The docker compose file syntax has changed since this answer was originally drafted.

Here is the updated syntax

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=letmein
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal
      - MYSQL_USER=drupal
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=drupal
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
  web:
    image: drupal
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/sites
      - /var/www/private
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, compose files are they way to go when it comes to managing docker content. The only thing I'm stuck on now is how to setup local drupal content to mount/link to the docker compose file. So I can dev and see the output on the docker VM

Comment: @VincentSpace The docker volumes listed in the compose file can be easily mapped to local directories in the dev space. Checkout the compose file syntax.

Comment: @Superbyte Could you be more specific? This is an old answer, with a compose file using version 1 syntax, but I tested it using version version 1.14.0 of docker-compose and it still works.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor thanks for your reply. My problem has been solved about 3 hours ago :)

Comment: Do you know how to do this in version 2 of docker-compose? If so I would be grateful if you would update the answer.

Answer (score 10):

The trick for me was to add the service name of the database container in the Drupal connection settings (settings.local.php) instead of 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1', like:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
'database' => 'database-name',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => 'root',
'host' => 'database-container-name',
'port' => '3306',
'driver' => 'mysql',
'prefix' => '',
);
```

Comment: This worked for me! Still, I'm curious how just adding `links` in `docker-compose.yml` didn't help!!

Comment: @RishiKulshreshtha Its depreciated https://docs.docker.com/network/links/