# Docker containers for Drupal environment not linked

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, drupal-8

I'm learning Docker and experimenting by installing Drupal. The process is to create 2 containers with one running Apache and the other running MySQL.

I have the following **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  d8:
    container_name: d8
    image: drupal
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8585:80"
    links: 
      - d8mysql:mysql
  d8mysql:
    container_name: d8mysql
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
      MYSQL_USER: user
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

And this **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM drupal:latest
FROM mysql:latest

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

When I run *docker-compose up*, both my containers are successfully created, I can login and interact with both.

The problem is the drupal site is not connected to the database. During the setup process, I supply the database name, user and password as identified in the *d8mysql* section. I confirmed the database and user are in the container **but** drupal can not connect. Screenshot below:

[image]

Looking at the **d8** section, I included **links** with an argument of the mysql container - which my [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422546/docker-drupal-container-linked-to-mysql-container-cant-connect-to-mysql-durin) indicates should do the trick but doesn't.

I also checked the */etc/hosts* file of the Apache container but it has no entry for the MySQL container which apparently should be there to facilitate the desired connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not defined tag for `mysql` image by default uses `latest` which for the time being is `8.0.18`.

Mysql 8 has changed its password authentication method which seems to cause incompatibility issues with drupal image. See [github issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/427).

One option is to install `mysql_native_password` plugin as proposed to the github issue above. I haven't tested it though.

The other options which **I have validated it is working** is to use an older docker tag for mysql image, e.g `mysql:5.7.28`

Working `docker-compose`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  d8:
    container_name: d8
    image: drupal
    ports:
      - "8585:80"
  d8mysql:
    container_name: d8mysql
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7.28
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
      MYSQL_USER: user
    # This is obsolete if you don't plan to connect to this db server from another machine outside docker network
    # ports:
    #   - "3306:3306"
```

Notes:

- I didn't use your `Dockerfile`, so I removed build section
- Your `Dockerfile` does not do anything special. When defining multiple `FROM` instructions only the later is effective.
- I removed link section as it is [not required](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links). `Docker-compose` by default creates an isolated network in which containers are added when stack starts. In this network, declared services names(`d8`,`d8mysql` for your case) act as domain names. Thus a container can access another via that name.

Comment: Thanks. I used version 5.7.28 as you suggested and drupal progressed beyond the database config section. Much appreciated

Comment: @sisko Happy to help. I updated my answer to include some extra info about why communication is possible without links.

Comment: And, mysql_native_password did the trick with mysql:latest. Just had to include     command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password in the db service data