# Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client, in docker-compose file

Tags: mysql, docker, authentication, docker-compose

am using mysql:8 for docker image for DB connection to the microservices.
but while start compose up i can't able to connect the mysql to the microservices

code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
   **errno: 1251,
   sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
   sqlState: '08004',
   fatal: true**

am using docker-compose version 2.2
am also not able to connect to mysql workbench

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59394010/9381897) and [this](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/424#issuecomment-387403312)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ER\_NOT\_SUPPORTED\_AUTH\_MODE - MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946270/er-not-supported-auth-mode-mysql-server)